# Is a Python list's += operator equivalent to append() or extend()?

Tags: python, list, append, operators, extend

Python lists have a `+=` operator as well as `append` and `extend` methods.

If `l` is a list, is `l += ...` equivalent to `l.append(...)`, `l.extend(...)`, both, or neither?

Comment: Did you try it?  `l += 4` gives an error; `l += [4]` adds `4` to the list.

Comment: You can find out what various expressions evaluate to by entering them into the Python interpreter. Feel free to play around with it and try different things (I do this often; it's helpful).

Comment: When applied to a list, `+=` is mostly equivalent to `extend`, but there can be some subtle scoping differences in a function context in the absence of `global` and `nonlocal`.  In this case, `+=` will force the creation of a local, while `extend` will not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In python += on a list is equivalent to `extend` method on that list.